# Is it possible to rename network interfaces in system preferences?

Tags: catalina, system-settings

Is there a way to rename USB Ethernet interfaces in System Preferences? I'm running macOS Catalina.

I have 2 USB Ethernet adapters - both are AX8817. Kinda hard to tell them apart.

I'm in this menu quite often, changing IPs. Would be nice to have some control over the names used here.

[image: NICs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename them using the cogwheel at the bottom of the window.